# A conversão de código ASCII para caracteres não funciona

Tags: java, android, ascii

Em primeiro lugar, eu sou novato no desenvolvimento do Android. Eu gostaria de saber por que meu aplicativo trava quando eu tento converter o código ASCII para caracteres.

```
private String crip(String str, String psw) {
    int code = 0;
    String full_word="";
    for (int i= 0; i <= str.length(); i++) {
        code=(int)str.charAt(i); // Crashes aqui (eu acho)
        full_word+=code;
    }
    return full_word;
}
```

E no evento onClick:

```
crip.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!psw.getText().toString().isEmpty() && !str.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            out.setText(crip(str.getText().toString(), psw.getText().toString()));
        }

    }
});
```

Há algo de errado?

Comment: Você está usando `setOnClickListener` em um método que retorna uma string???

Comment: Você precisa depurar seu código. Veja que valor a expressão `(int)str.charAt(i)` tem quando o problema acontece.

Comment: Por favor, note que `String` é uma sequência de UTF-16, e não de ASCII. A diferença mais importante é que qualquer sequência de ASCII é válida, mas existem sequências de UTF-16 que não o são -- não é possível reorganizar ou fazer aritmética com caracteres UTF-16 arbitrariamente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meu Java é bem fraco, mas vejo um problema aqui:

```
for (int i= 0; i <= str.length(); i++)
```

Você está iterando um caractere a mais. O código deveria ser:

```
for (int i= 0; i < str.length(); i++)
```

Comment: Independente de isso ser ou não o problema do OP, isso por si só provoca um erro. Bem notado!

Comment: Se só isso resolver o problema dele, ainda tem outro em potencial: o nome do método e dos parâmetros dá a entender que ele está tentando fazer um hash de senha ou algo do tipo, usando códigos ASCII. Não me parece uma boa, mas também não é a minha área...

Comment: E além disso, a variável `psw` não é utilizada